# Migrate SAPUI5 Fiori application from Neo to Clould Foundry

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-foundry

I have some SAPUI5 Fiori applications developed using SAP WEB IDE in the Neo platform. Now I need to migrate those applications to the cloud foundry environment. So far as I checked there are few differences in the application files of NEO & Cloud Foundry. 
eg:

Neo has **neo-app.json** and cloud foundry has **xs-app.json**

Are there any guidance or information related on correctly migrating SAPUI5 apps from Neo to Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed not that many differences but there is some different handling in terms of tooling files, etc ...

I would propose to create a new multi-target test project using the provided standard templates and then add a UI5 test template subproject.

That will give you an idea of how the CF UI5 project structure looks like and which files are being generated.

It also depends on whether you are going to use the new HTML5-repo application architecture or not.  That newer format has more impact and changes under the hood.